# Converting a custom dataset to TUDataset format

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to apply a deep-learning model to my dataset. In the original code, TUDataset is used and I honestly don't understand its structure and how to convert my data to a suitable replacement for the original input.

I need to first understand what is the correct structure of the input so that I can convert mine to it and use their model, but I couldn't figure that out.

Also, does anyone have a suggestion on how to approach the task of a method reproducing from a publication, in general?

The method that I am trying to reproduce is [SAGPool](https://github.com/inyeoplee77/SAGPool).